# Protocol not avaible SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

Sometimes I can access the server, but most of the time it returns the following error.

```
ssh -vvv gilberto@146.164.6.223 -p 23490
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 146.164.6.223 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 146.164.6.223 [146.164.6.223] port 23490.
debug1: connect to address 146.164.6.223 port 23490: Protocol not available
ssh: connect to host 146.164.6.223 port 23490: Protocol not available
```

I'm trying to access as follows:" ssh gilberto@146.164.6.223 -p 23490", I'm using Ubuntu 20.4.

Can someone help me?

I already tried other ports but I get timeout error

Comment: Welcome to SU. Have you checked what you find if you put `ssh "protocol not available"` to a search engine like google?

Comment: For some SSH versions the argument for the port is `-P` (capital P).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: This is Rio UNI IP address. Wouldn't it be easiest to solve by talking to the UNI IT people?

Answer (score 2):

"Protocol not available" (-ENOPROTOOPT) is the translation of an ICMP error packet, specifically "Destination Unreachable" with code "Protocol Unreachable". Since the protocol in question (TCP) is fairly standard and definitely supported by SSH-capable servers, the ICMP error packet must have been generated by a firewall on the server side – e.g. by an iptables "reject" rule.

Comment: Interesting. I just tested again and now it failed to me too...